# CUDA Thread communication and synchronization mechanisms

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I am a bit confused about the **thread communication and synchronization mechanisms** provided by CUDA. Can someone help me to verify my assumptions below ?

1. **Threads within a warp** communicate using shared or global memory and synchronize using implicit synchronization
2. **Warps within a thread block** communicate using shared or global memory and synchronize using barrier synchronization
3. **Thread blocks within a given grid or kernel** communicate using global memory and synchronize using atomic memory operations
4. **Thread blocks from different grids or kernels** communicate using  global memory and synchronize using implicit synchronization

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: If you can reword so that this is not a yes/no question, we can reopen and possibly get some better answers.

Comment: Being a yes/no question doesn't mean it isn't a real question. The poster put some work in here, it seems a shame it was closed.